# Golang best practices: empty array response or error?

Tags: arrays, go, error-handling

What are best practices in terms of error handling for a function that accepts slice of objects and returns another slice of objects (ideally of same length as input array) along with error as follows:

```
func ([]interface{}) ([]interface{}, error)
```

One way is whenever you get an error for processing one of the objects in a slice, you return an error response, but that way at the receiving function, if you don't discard all slice elements, error response becomes of little use merely telling us that processing of one of the elements or all failed. Another way is you return an error when none of the elements get processed but again this is of little use I feel. One more way is you don't include error as return object and instead with every slice element struct, have it's own error object as a composite so you can send elementwise error as output.

The best way obviously depends on the particular scenario, however, I want to know if there are any best practices people follow or any design patterns around this problem.

PS: This was one of the closest questions, however since its accepting single object as input, not very relevant:
[Return empty array or error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852784/return-empty-array-or-error)

Comment: edited. Does that mean I should return an `error` value even if there is error in processing one of the elements. Since in golang, `error` is more flexible compared to let's say exceptions, I felt there is more freedom in using it the way is most beneficial depending on use case.

Comment: See [1](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/datastore#MultiError) and [2](https://godoc.org/github.com/hashicorp/go-multierror) for examples of how to handle errors on batch operations.

Comment: MultiError would be even more trickier since then you have two different outputs, slice of objects and MultiError which is essentially slice of errors and you need to correlate between two (pythonic zip?). Any concurrent processing of inputs in this case becomes very difficult like @torek mentioned? Wouldn't including an `error` inside slice element struct be a better choice?

Comment: datastore.MultiError values have a one-to-one correspondence with the input elements.  Correlation is easy (use the same index for inputs and errors).  Concurrency does not add any complication (just pass the index around),

Comment: There is no best-practice for a question like this. As you said "The best way obviously depends on the particular scenario", making this question opinion-based. If you focus on a specific scenario, then an unopinionated answer can likely be provided.

Comment: Aren't best practices mass opinions?

Answer (score 0):

> ... a function that accepts [slice of interface representing an] array of objects and returns another [slice of interface representing an] array of objects along with error ...

You have not told us enough to go on.

- Does the returned slice actually have anything to do with the parameter slice?
- If so, what relationship do they have?  For instance, perhaps the returned slice should be half the size of the input slice, and an error occurs if and only if the number of input objects is odd, in which case the last input object has been ignored.
- Must inputs be processed in order, or will they be processed in parallel?

> One more way is you don't include error as return object and instead with every array object struct, have it's own error object as a composite so you can send elementwise error as output.

This is probably a wise approach if the outputs are one-to-one with the inputs and you intend to handle them in parallel and/or continue processing the remaining inputs upon reaching one bad one.  Equivalently, you can have the output slice include an error.

It's really very problem-dependent.

Edit: consider, e.g., the following (which I don't claim is *good*, mind you):

```
const maxWorkers = 10 // tunable

// Process a slice of T's in parallel.  The results are either an
// R for each T, or an error.  Caller provides the actual function
// f(T), which returns R + error (an empty/zero R for error).
func ProcessInParallel(input []T, f func(T) (R, error)) ([]interface{}, error) {
    // Make one channel for sending work to workers,
    // and one for receiving results from workers.
    type Todo struct {
        i    int // the index of the item
        item T   // the item to work on
    }
    workChan := make(chan Todo)
    type Done struct {
        i int   // the index of the item worked on
        r R     // result, if we have one
        e error // error, if we have one
    }
    doneChan := make(chan Done)

    // Spin off workers: maxWorkers or len(input),
    // whichever is smaller.
    n := len(input)
    if n > maxWorkers {
        n = maxWorkers
    }
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(i int) {
            for todo := range workChan {
                i := todo.i
                r, err := f(input[i])
                doneChan <- Done{i, r, err}
            }
            wg.Done()
        }(i)
    }

    // Close doneChan when all workers finish.
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(doneChan)
    }()

    // Hand out work to workers (then close work channel).
    go func() {
        for i := range input {
            workChan <- Todo{i, input[i]}
        }
        close(workChan)
    }()

    // Collect results.
    var anyErr error
    ret := make([]interface{}, len(input))
    for done := range doneChan {
        i := done.i
        r, err := done.r, done.e
        if err != nil {
            anyErr = err
            ret[i] = err
        } else {
            ret[i] = r
        }
    }
    return ret, anyErr
}
```

This has an overall error return, *and* it returns a slice of `interface{}`.  This means you can immediately tell if everything worked.  However, it's kind of annoying to use:

```
ret, err := ProcessInParallel(arg, f)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("some inputs failed")
    for i := range ret {
        if e, ok := ret[i].(error); ok {
            fmt.Printf("%d: failed: %v\n", i, e)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("%d: %s\n", i, ret[i].(R))
        }
    }
} else {
    fmt.Println("all inputs were good")
    for i := range ret {
        fmt.Printf("%d: %s\n", i, ret[i].(R))
    }
}
```

Why bother with the all-error summary?

Instead, we could have `ProcessInParallel` return `[]R, []error`, for instance, or—probably better—use a simple `error` interface return value to store a [MultiError](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/datastore#MultiError) as [Cerise Limón suggested in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59331825/golang-best-practices-empty-array-response-or-error/59331859?noredirect=1#comment104862793_59331825):

```
ret, err := ProcessInParallel(arg, f)
if err != nil {
    if merr, ok := err.(datastore.MultiError); ok {
        // merr[i] indicates the various failed items
        // any ret[i] for which merr[i] is nil is OK
    }
} else {
    // all ret[i] are ok
}
```

A working example that *doesn't* use `MultiError` is [here](https://play.golang.org/p/BJVvLQSWLkv).

A working example that *does* use `MultiError` is [here](https://play.golang.org/p/J8t9g-zB6rQ).

Comment: edited. If the lengths of input and output slices are same, how would the answer differ if it's processed sequentially or concurrently?

Comment: Well: consider if you're processing sequentially starting at index 0. You stop at the *first error* and return a slice of, say, length 10, when the input had 20 elements. You now know, in the caller, that the error occurred after processing 10 successfully, so input[0] through input[9] are good, and the error applies to input[10].

Comment: If your function has divided up the work, though, perhaps inputs 0 through 4 are correct, 5 is bad, and 10 through 15 are correct.  The output can have ten "good" values (spread across 15 total "returned" values) and an error. There's no clear way to know that the error applies to input[5].

Comment: Yeah right. In the cases I need to process them concurrently, I add an Index fields in the struct as well similar to Error field I proposed. However, the struct becomes too bulky with all these extra fields :(

Answer (score 0):

While Go supports multiple return values, when one of the return types is an `error`, it is meant to process either `error` or the other return values and not both. It means that when `error` is not `nil`, the other return values has no specific meaning and should not be processed.

In your case, I'd personally prefer to use an *iterator* pattern, similar to what is implemented for [database/sql.Rows](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows), such that:

```golang
func X(values []interface{}) *Result
```

The `Result` would hold all processed slice elements associated with their errors. Somewhere in the code I would write something like this:

```golang
result := X(values)
for result.Next() {
  if err := result.Err(); err != nil {
    // Handle the err for this specific element.
    // Whether continue or fail the whole process.
  }

  v := result.Cur()
  // Process current element.
}
```

Comment: "While Go supports multiple return values, when one of the return types is an error, it is meant to process either error or the other return values and not both." This is entirely false. The most noticeable examples of having both an error and a return value is any method that implements `io.Reader`, which the document says: "When Read encounters an error or end-of-file condition after successfully reading n > 0 bytes, it returns the number of bytes read." The same goes with `io.Writer`.

Comment: And aside from package `io`, `go/types` has `*Config.Check` whose doc say “Check type-checks a package and returns the resulting package object and the first error if any.”; `go/parser` has `ParseDir` which states "If a parse error occurred, a non-nil but incomplete map and the first error encountered are returned. " in its doc. There are much more in and beyond the standard packages and source code of official Go.

Comment: Your design is clean and neat in many ways, but having to access the result one by one (i.e., impossible to re-slice and index) might be a problem for some purposes.

Comment: @leafbebop The most Go funcs and methods does not guarantee to return a valid value when an error occurs, however in almost all cases they'd return a zero value. So I'd prefer to not trust the value when err is non-nil, since this is the default behavior, unless (in rare cases) explicitly stated in the docs.

Comment: @leafbebop Error handling in Go is hard, and it's hard for a reason. Re-slicing the result can always occur with another helper func.

Comment: whether or not a function returns a valid value while there's an error is a design decision by the owner of that function, and shall be documented. Trust the document. If there is no document, it is a good reason to not use that function. Errors are just values, and values can be programmed. They are not some magic  `maybe`. They can be perfectly programmed to be returned with valid values.

Comment: error handling in Go is not harder, it's more explicit. Error handling is an essential part of code and logic, if it needs more logic than printing or panicking - or handling one by one, just write complex code. I think the goal here, like other Go code, is to be clean and robust, not easy or smart. But that being said, I don't think your design is bad - it might not suit for some cases and might be great for others.

Comment: I downvoted because of the false claim I pointed out, not because the design.